# Rolling regression in R for Taylor Rule

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, rolling-computation

first let's a look at my data :

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(0, 7776000, 15638400, 23587200, 
31536000, 39312000, 47174400, 55123200, 63072000, 70934400, 78796800, 
86745600, 94694400, 102470400, 110332800, 118281600, 126230400, 
134006400, 141868800, 149817600, 157766400, 165542400, 173404800, 
181353600, 189302400, 197164800, 205027200, 212976000, 220924800, 
228700800, 236563200, 244512000, 252460800, 260236800, 268099200, 
276048000, 283996800, 291772800, 299635200, 307584000, 315532800, 
323395200, 331257600, 339206400, 347155200, 354931200, 362793600, 
370742400, 378691200, 386467200, 394329600, 402278400, 410227200, 
418003200, 425865600, 433814400, 441763200, 449625600, 457488000, 
465436800, 473385600, 481161600, 489024000, 496972800, 504921600, 
512697600, 520560000, 528508800, 536457600, 544233600, 552096000, 
560044800, 567993600, 575856000, 583718400, 591667200, 599616000, 
607392000, 615254400, 623203200, 631152000, 638928000, 646790400, 
654739200, 662688000, 670464000, 678326400, 686275200, 694224000, 
702086400, 709948800, 717897600, 725846400, 733622400, 741484800, 
749433600, 757382400, 765158400, 773020800, 780969600, 788918400, 
796694400, 804556800, 812505600, 820454400, 828316800, 836179200, 
844128000, 852076800, 859852800, 867715200, 875664000, 883612800, 
891388800, 899251200, 907200000, 915148800, 922924800, 930787200, 
938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 970358400, 978307200, 
986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 1017619200, 1025481600, 
1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 1057017600, 1064966400, 1072915200, 
1080777600, 1088640000, 1096588800, 1104537600, 1112313600, 1120176000, 
1128124800, 1136073600, 1143849600, 1151712000, 1159660800, 1167609600, 
1175385600, 1183248000, 1191196800, 1199145600, 1207008000, 1214870400, 
1222819200, 1230768000, 1238544000, 1246406400, 1254355200, 1262304000, 
1270080000, 1277942400, 1285891200, 1293840000, 1301616000, 1309478400, 
1317427200, 1325376000, 1333238400, 1341100800, 1349049600, 1356998400, 
1364774400, 1372636800, 1380585600, 1388534400, 1396310400, 1404172800, 
1412121600, 1420070400, 1427846400, 1435708800, 1443657600, 1451606400, 
1459468800, 1467331200, 1475280000, 1483228800, 1491004800, 1498867200, 
1506816000, 1514764800, 1522540800, 1530403200, 1538352000, 1546300800, 
1554076800, 1561939200, 1569888000, 1577836800, 1585699200, 1593561600, 
1601510400, 1609459200, 1617235200, 1625097600, 1633046400, 1640995200, 
1648771200, 1656633600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    TauxInflation = c(5.4823, 5.60912, 5.00048, 5.03693, 5.15038, 
    5.06558, 5.27259, 4.76363, 4.7685, 4.05382, 3.99109, 4.4431, 
    4.06518, 5.01081, 6.04241, 6.79575, 7.57091, 8.44536, 9.48761, 
    10.50588, 10.92482, 9.97655, 8.73418, 7.39557, 6.11817, 5.61554, 
    5.12224, 5.24732, 5.8237, 6.24639, 6.16675, 6.54917, 6.38727, 
    6.91382, 7.42087, 7.30185, 7.68877, 8.25833, 8.77816, 8.57485, 
    8.87269, 8.79593, 8.85023, 9.65044, 10.22195, 9.79519, 9.41469, 
    8.4791, 7.15128, 6.43409, 5.95126, 5.22914, 4.58293, 4.00959, 
    3.64426, 3.36087, 3.62561, 3.73874, 3.56098, 3.54965, 3.52558, 
    3.30952, 3.01672, 2.82425, 2.32463, 2.05414, 1.85903, 1.84323, 
    1.98242, 2.30291, 2.6542, 2.91293, 3.06481, 3.35195, 3.80231, 
    3.8711, 4.1387, 4.23171, 3.75398, 3.59826, 3.63381, 3.69038, 
    3.82106, 3.85365, 3.75195, 3.3572, 3.27861, 3.12403, 2.50357, 
    2.36784, 2.07094, 2.16708, 2.35996, 2.35331, 2.46051, 2.31554, 
    2.23085, 2.11719, 2.096, 2.09326, 2.15924, 2.156, 2.07424, 
    2.01227, 1.94951, 1.88297, 1.7154, 1.76799, 1.88472, 1.67007, 
    1.77796, 1.5702, 1.11666, 1.14944, 1.14582, 1.09124, 1.26591, 
    1.41081, 1.33579, 1.61655, 1.96479, 2.21355, 2.44787, 2.43833, 
    2.43, 2.41109, 2.21433, 1.9787, 1.64133, 1.38047, 1.47007, 
    1.73593, 1.91419, 1.91253, 2.00069, 2.04317, 2.25486, 2.72204, 
    2.79724, 2.95777, 3.04905, 2.97154, 3.24514, 3.28203, 3.18786, 
    3.35086, 3.13403, 2.68894, 2.94813, 2.72556, 2.54336, 2.59435, 
    1.97737, 1.81389, 2.05202, 1.86227, 1.45534, 0.76702, 0.1202, 
    0.21249, 0.53464, 1.20187, 1.39857, 1.65745, 1.90524, 2.08038, 
    2.40232, 1.92884, 2.02063, 1.75938, 1.6583, 2.05037, 1.84065, 
    1.71994, 1.67215, 1.76398, 1.78068, 2.06748, 2.03227, 1.59489, 
    1.13753, 1.11277, 0.97329, 0.79597, 0.75111, 0.91615, 0.89533, 
    1.43648, 2.043, 1.64243, 1.87012, 2.03405, 2.13195, 2.68881, 
    2.51969, 2.28158, 2.05086, 1.74681, 1.73643, 1.64759, 1.66365, 
    0.72114, 1.26255, 1.53059, 2.38234, 4.36222, 5.03725, 6.11725, 
    6.93593, 7.61944, 7.14799), FEDFUND = c(8.57333333333333, 
    7.88666666666667, 6.70666666666667, 5.56666666666667, 3.85666666666667, 
    4.56666666666667, 5.47666666666667, 4.75, 3.54666666666667, 
    4.3, 4.74333333333333, 5.14666666666667, 6.53666666666667, 
    7.81666666666667, 10.56, 9.99666666666667, 9.32333333333333, 
    11.25, 12.09, 9.34666666666667, 6.30333333333333, 5.42, 6.16, 
    5.41333333333333, 4.82666666666667, 5.19666666666667, 5.28333333333333, 
    4.87333333333333, 4.66, 5.15666666666667, 5.82, 6.51333333333333, 
    6.75666666666667, 7.28333333333333, 8.1, 9.58333333333333, 
    10.0733333333333, 10.18, 10.9466666666667, 13.5766666666667, 
    15.0466666666667, 12.6866666666667, 9.83666666666667, 15.8533333333333, 
    16.57, 17.78, 17.5766666666667, 13.5866666666667, 14.2266666666667, 
    14.5133333333333, 11.0066666666667, 9.28666666666667, 8.65333333333333, 
    8.80333333333333, 9.46, 9.43, 9.68666666666667, 10.5566666666667, 
    11.39, 9.26666666666667, 8.47666666666667, 7.92333333333333, 
    7.9, 8.10333333333333, 7.82666666666667, 6.92, 6.20666666666667, 
    6.26666666666667, 6.22, 6.65, 6.84333333333333, 6.91666666666667, 
    6.66333333333333, 7.15666666666667, 7.98333333333333, 8.47, 
    9.44333333333333, 9.72666666666667, 9.08333333333333, 8.61333333333333, 
    8.25, 8.24333333333333, 8.16, 7.74333333333333, 6.42666666666667, 
    5.86333333333333, 5.64333333333333, 4.81666666666667, 4.02333333333333, 
    3.77, 3.25666666666667, 3.03666666666667, 3.04, 3, 3.06, 
    2.99, 3.21333333333333, 3.94, 4.48666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 
    5.81, 6.02, 5.79666666666667, 5.72, 5.36333333333333, 5.24333333333333, 
    5.30666666666667, 5.28, 5.27666666666667, 5.52333333333333, 
    5.53333333333333, 5.50666666666667, 5.52, 5.5, 5.53333333333333, 
    4.86, 4.73333333333333, 4.74666666666667, 5.09333333333333, 
    5.30666666666667, 5.67666666666667, 6.27333333333333, 6.52, 
    6.47333333333333, 5.59333333333333, 4.32666666666667, 3.49666666666667, 
    2.13333333333333, 1.73333333333333, 1.75, 1.74, 1.44333333333333, 
    1.25, 1.24666666666667, 1.01666666666667, 0.996666666666667, 
    1.00333333333333, 1.01, 1.43333333333333, 1.95, 2.47, 2.94333333333333, 
    3.46, 3.98, 4.45666666666667, 4.90666666666667, 5.24666666666667, 
    5.24666666666667, 5.25666666666667, 5.25, 5.07333333333333, 
    4.49666666666667, 3.17666666666667, 2.08666666666667, 1.94, 
    0.506666666666667, 0.183333333333333, 0.18, 0.156666666666667, 
    0.12, 0.133333333333333, 0.193333333333333, 0.186666666666667, 
    0.186666666666667, 0.156666666666667, 0.0933333333333333, 
    0.0833333333333333, 0.0733333333333333, 0.103333333333333, 
    0.153333333333333, 0.143333333333333, 0.16, 0.143333333333333, 
    0.116666666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 0.0866666666666667, 
    0.0733333333333333, 0.0933333333333333, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 
    0.123333333333333, 0.136666666666667, 0.16, 0.36, 0.373333333333333, 
    0.396666666666667, 0.45, 0.7, 0.95, 1.15333333333333, 1.20333333333333, 
    1.44666666666667, 1.73666666666667, 1.92333333333333, 2.22, 
    2.40333333333333, 2.39666666666667, 2.19, 1.64333333333333, 
    1.26, 0.06, 0.0933333333333333, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.09, 0.08, 
    0.12, 0.77, 2.19), Outputgap = c(-0.108421271221732, -0.793540803324699, 
    -0.673434946185341, -2.49139223428573, -0.606115631308476, 
    -0.839127301417564, -0.799617078770942, -1.34364801366606, 
    -0.323893557363418, 1.12729111683781, 1.26335603172645, 2.12598968196768, 
    3.79412829141569, 4.02898654326197, 2.59608734023255, 2.67105285216393, 
    0.901242542659872, 0.26207858258918, -1.53108949745756, -2.72900160745802, 
    -4.68414581888807, -4.75061588966659, -3.86249422177005, 
    -3.30959064732945, -1.88020350150529, -1.91346313667353, 
    -2.14330080991953, -2.2075777559316, -1.84843848967974, -0.757733747755038, 
    0.201879387103812, -0.635617301289618, -1.16849700780273, 
    1.76557195388083, 1.8866633187927, 2.34105200416243, 1.59935422492546, 
    0.82787135578371, 0.688778739089824, 0.193033881714488, -0.174352878150304, 
    -2.8278131438863, -3.46929432644066, -2.22843980775495, -0.934688266036425, 
    -2.32285759360661, -1.842342200882, -3.61879470492801, -5.82598236527991, 
    -6.11593899551093, -7.19493429874133, -7.88096385909115, 
    -7.3877771047461, -6.0235128244415, -4.91280710242111, -3.73228797006592, 
    -2.76574071507222, -1.94771760597047, -1.8768839913704, -1.95099829810977, 
    -1.87648656492425, -1.88267466321731, -1.25056464464826, 
    -1.36875054651411, -1.28627159865532, -1.66567002942245, 
    -1.54062547330455, -1.8180911651805, -1.88096873248047, -1.60931312146061, 
    -1.53391898358279, -0.625388849393298, -0.881823636705972, 
    -0.350326083507105, -0.527949007358343, 0.0381311999033859, 
    0.303204940923941, 0.326698414309294, 0.338080252212445, 
    -0.184094158155907, 0.19827171920647, -0.132352341335226, 
    -0.736735870585722, -2.28365818563812, -3.36375646042349, 
    -3.22168545981695, -3.33590402627844, -3.60038227715095, 
    -3.05370049178378, -2.61865442014903, -2.28754827088983, 
    -1.90844675144132, -2.38757592799754, -2.47308240815232, 
    -2.66553229860525, -2.00752649190096, -1.72524717759255, 
    -1.06633060045326, -1.16489815464656, -0.71349108021004, 
    -1.0374426738315, -1.41794498675899, -1.2537641415948, -1.26762176765226, 
    -1.21884075701403, -0.305974829790867, -0.19350822328051, 
    0.0150407045090304, -0.207254381403626, 0.541406778637158, 
    0.84890985524364, 0.740745751527986, 0.753957453402937, 0.671584644954848, 
    0.907080142468449, 1.49825860270568, 1.40757480596351, 1.2059811822373, 
    1.49093914934045, 2.09073295987261, 1.40366434830704, 2.21332785327486, 
    1.33622018608941, 1.01381494597032, -0.176514190006713, -0.367073431090808, 
    -1.51914010665274, -1.95354646708477, -1.81143652581517, 
    -1.8510070072902, -2.08171333492998, -2.56472180866248, -2.66607766988254, 
    -2.40494646284141, -1.38922721751737, -0.869268170333065, 
    -0.928038684413967, -0.789297985130645, -0.501182802697197, 
    -0.136371386557098, 0.332489649415798, 0.200815070683697, 
    0.379377318008107, 0.35694021226986, 1.13060217942788, 0.814758486588903, 
    0.429248748920743, 0.762090719047189, 0.548015439735484, 
    0.67865570786172, 0.771103248713783, 0.876392638175842, -0.0317702375943376, 
    0.0622689944924331, -0.914045501910472, -3.48607182766317, 
    -4.9790944063897, -5.47937745680808, -5.45578605545283, -4.7557152648726, 
    -4.59052187476466, -3.98732296574784, -3.58154315382725, 
    -3.42904079459916, -4.02029873260861, -3.74245507289448, 
    -4.16317009943925, -3.48324168581536, -3.09882381387287, 
    -3.07261055540131, -3.3250444364821, -3.64504048451998, -3.24310235721438, 
    -3.54528088067744, -3.2215718476605, -2.97833666514625, -3.76282387082635, 
    -2.97716638338436, -2.30675296601837, -2.3292276209052, -1.99692844628985, 
    -1.88944382221384, -2.0273802474028, -2.32951661189567, -2.19415453185816, 
    -2.33092846992939, -2.1700397537368, -2.10661426749558, -2.10915827953466, 
    -2.03636394034077, -1.65736004346529, -1.11133725575327, 
    -0.878552422850792, -0.650842835588467, -0.406639899050571, 
    -0.697743416833746, -0.629675978717122, -0.434271331359682, 
    -0.0234504589473474, -0.0515359011872862, -1.6798575188629, 
    -10.4174376471986, -3.76590960219303, -3.2465895658016, -2.18008204845228, 
    -0.956479479288248, -0.75784373767203, 0.461432468845234, 
    -0.40669917447496, -1.02436274885355, -0.709364420331966)), row.names = c(NA, 
-211L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have all this data from 1970 to 2022, the last 6 columns are fed governors, binary columns, 1 when the individual is the governor 0 when he is not. My goal si to do a rolling regression using the time of each governor as windows. At tried several thing, the follow code that i'm gonna show you worked but a messed up something at one point and i dont know what, so I need help :

```
df<- read_xlsx("my_path")

# add a semester colums
df$trimestre <- seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), by = "quarter", length.out = nrow(df))

# fonction my_lm
my_lm <- function(df) {
  data_df <- as.data.frame(df) # conversion en data.frame
  lm(FEDFUND ~ TauxInflation + Outputgap + Burns + Volcker + Greenspan + Bernanke + Janet + Powell, data = data_df)
}

# windows definition
widths <- c(sum(df$Burns), sum(df$Volcker), sum(df$Greenspan), sum(df$Bernanke), sum(df$Janet), sum(df$Powell))
aligns <- rep("right", length(widths))

# creation of zoo time serie from my data frame
df_zoo <- read.zoo(df, index.column = "trimestre", FUN = as.yearqtr)

# Creation of rolling time serie
coefficients_rolling <- rollapply(df_zoo, width = widths, by = sum(widths),
                                  align = "right", FUN = my_lm, by.column = TRUE)

# Extract of coef
coef_df <- as.data.frame(t(coefficients_rolling))
names(coef_df) <- c("Intercept", "TauxInflation", "Outputgap", "Burns", "Volcker", "Greenspan", "Bernanke", "Janet", "Powell")
```

the result i get is the following :

```
> coefficients_rolling <- rollapply(df_zoo, width = widths, by = sum(widths),
+                                   align = "right", FUN = my_lm, by.column = TRUE)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'FEDFUND' not found
Called from: eval(predvars, data, env)
```

So it's weird because the FEDFUND variable is indeed in my data but roll seems to not find it :

```
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  Date                TauxInflat~1 FEDFUND Outpu~2 Burns Volcker Green~3 Berna~4 Janet
  <dttm>                     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00         5.48    8.57  -0.108     1       0       0       0     0
2 1970-04-01 00:00:00         5.61    7.89  -0.794     1       0       0       0     0
3 1970-07-01 00:00:00         5.00    6.71  -0.673     1       0       0       0     0
4 1970-10-01 00:00:00         5.04    5.57  -2.49      1       0       0       0     0
5 1971-01-01 00:00:00         5.15    3.86  -0.606     1       0       0       0     0
6 1971-04-01 00:00:00         5.07    4.57  -0.839     1       0       0       0     0
# ... with 2 more variables: Powell <dbl>, trimestre <date>, and abbreviated variable
#   names 1: TauxInflation, 2: Outputgap, 3: Greenspan, 4: Bernanke
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

At the end I expect to have the coefficient of my rolling regression and see if they are stable for each governors etc

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular provide your input using `dput`  so that it is easily reproducible by others.

Comment: Please make the code and input consistent.  Get rid of the xlsx part, remove library statements for packages not used, sort out the difference between `df` and `data`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it's done thanks and I stlii go the same error even after fixing the data/df inconsistency

Comment: df can only have one non-numeric column and that represents the time index (unless split= is used  and that can only be used if it makes sense).  The lm is attempting to use columns that are not in df.  The width definition seems invalid.  align= must be a scalar.  The function in rollapply must return a scalar or vector.  The library statement is missing.  read_xlsx is extraneous and should be removed.  Suggest you read the help file for rollapply carefully and also the vignettes that come with zoo.